# Directive - Dependency Injection do not resolve (controllerAs syntax)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am Trying to follow the rules on https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075 , and i am trying to inject the dependencies, and unfortunatly, it fails on GetDiscussionThreadListService

HTML :

```
<discussion-parent someParam></discussion-parent>
```

JS :

```
  var xDiscussionsDirectives = angular.module('xxx.discussions.parent', ['ngResource']).directive('discussionParent', discussionParrentDirective);

function discussionParrentDirective() {
  var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        discussionType: '@docDiscussionType',
    },
    templateUrl: 'modules/discussions/views/ParentDiscussionTemplate.aspx',
    replace: false,
    controller: discussionParrentDirectiveController,
    //controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
    };
    return directive; 
}


discussionParrentDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$filter', '$interval', '$modal', '$timeout', 'GetDiscussionThreadListService'];


function discussionParrentDirectiveController($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    GetDiscussionThreadListService.get({
            //some params
        }, function (data) {
}
   }
```

> ReferenceError: GetDiscussionThreadListService is not defined
>       (xxx.discussions.parrent.js:278)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to declare this module in your function arguments list like this :

```
    discussionParrentDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$filter', '$interval', '$modal', '$timeout', 'GetDiscussionThreadListService'];

    function discussionParrentDirectiveController($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $filter, $interval, $modal, $timeout, GetDiscussionThreadListService) {
        GetDiscussionThreadListService.get({
                //some params
            }, function (data) {
    }
```

This way your variable `GetDiscussionThreadListService` will be define in your scope.

One alternative is to import is as first to avoid all those useless module (which are injected by the way).

```
    discussionParrentDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', 'GetDiscussionThreadListService', '$location', '$filter', '$interval', '$modal', '$timeout'];

    function discussionParrentDirectiveController($scope, $route, $routeParams, GetDiscussionThreadListService) {
        GetDiscussionThreadListService.get({
                //some params
            }, function (data) {
    }
```

I also use this styleguide it is a great one, continue with it because totally think it worth it.

Comment: good point, it was the same in style guide, but with comment 
  "// Injecting $scope just for comparison" so i was a bit confused about that

Answer (score 1):

`discussionParrentDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', '$filter', '$interval', '$modal', '$timeout', 'GetDiscussionThreadListService']`

And

`function discussionParrentDirectiveController($scope, $element, $attrs)`

need to match

the `$inject` purpose is to handle issues like the minimization of javascript, so the module names need to match. In your function you need to have the same parameters.

`function discussionParrentDirectiveController($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $filter, $interval, $modal, $timeout, GetDiscussionThreadListService)`