# Access vm property in AngularJS directive with ControllerAs inside controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In another question I got [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31357883/4981358). 
(Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/lYg15Xpb3CsbQGIb37ya?p=preview)

The source from this:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    this.scenarios = []
    $timeout(function() {
         this.scenarios.push({name: 21});    
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});

MyDirectiveController.$inject = [];

function MyDirectiveController() {
     var vm = this;
     // code of this question...
}

app.directive('myDirective', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{vm.scenarios[0].name}}</div>',
        scope: {
        scenarios: '='
        },
        controller: MyDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        replace: true
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    {{vm.scenarios}}
    <my-directive scenarios="vm.scenarios"></my-directive>
</body>
```

My question now is, how can I access vm.scenarios in the controller?

```
var vm = this;
console.log(vm.scenarios); // returns []
```

When I log this:

```
var vm = this;
console.log(vm);
```

It returns `Object { scenarios: Array[0] }`, but when I inspect it in the browser, `scenarios` contains the value as expected because it has been updated after the timeout of 1 second.

But I need to map the `scenarios` inside the controller when they're bound to the `scenario` property:

```
vm.myscenarios = vm.scenarios.map(function(scenario) { 
     // .... 
})
```

How can I do this? Should I watch `vm.scenarios` for changes?

Comment: this is all kinds of wrong.  you have an array, and you are writing a directive to display only the first element of the array? why not use `ng-repeat="scenario in scenarios"` instead and let angular deal with everything else?

Comment: The `{{vm.scenarios[0].name}}` is just to show that the binding works. The `scenarios` are populated using `$http` and `$timeout` is just to show the delay.

Comment: ok, so what, the directive is going to show all the scenarios? and then, you want to interact with one of them, and have it bubble back up to the controller for the page rather than the controller for the directive? it's hard to make out what you are having trouble with, or what that `.map` has to do with the directive.

Comment: `MainCtrl` gets the `scenarios` via `$http` and they're bound to my directive using `<my-directive scenarios="vm.scenarios"></my-directive>`. But before my directive can display them, they need to be modified (the required schema is different from the one received by `$http`). But my directive cannot use `$http` because when `vm.myscenarios` gets changed, `vm.scenarios` (thus the `scenarios` of `MainCtrl`) has to be updated with this changes also.

Comment: as an off topic, this is why I recommend you don't use `vm.` for everything.  you should use something that helps you tell which controller is which, whenever possible.  `controllerAs: 'myDirective'` and `MainCtrl as main` would make it much easier to identify when you are accessing the `main` scope vs the `myDirective` scope.

Comment: yes, but what is `vm.myscenario`? you don't even show that in this code; again, even in the directive, you could use `ng-repeat` and access the specific `scenario` that is in the `scenarios` array without using `.map`

Comment: and what does 'the required schema is different' actually mean?

Comment: Lets consider `vm.scenarios` looks like this `[{ name : "test"}]`. But I need this `[{ fullname : "test", size: 4 }]`. Now `vm.myscenarios` should contain the result of this mapping function. And this result should be bound to the template of my directive this way: `<div><input type="text" ng-model="vm.myscenarios[0].fullname"></div>` (yes it could be used `ng-repeat` to iterate over them). And when `vm.myscenarios[0].fullname` has been changed, `vm.scenarios[0].name` should reflect this change.

Comment: I still don't see the logic here; what *else* is the directive doing that requires the property names to change?  Rendering a template definitely can be done without doing what you describe; for that matter, using map logic in the rendering process poses all kinds of performance issues...

Comment: The problem is that the UI to edit the scenarios is more than just a input element and thus cannot be bound before mapping them to the model which is editable by the UI.

Comment: I obviously won't be able to provide any answer here, as I've never seen anything even similar.

Comment: Anyway thanks for listening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Directive - Dependency Injection do not resolve (controllerAs syntax)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747428/directive-dependency-injection-do-not-resolve-controlleras-syntax)